# Metric mapping to sets other than $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, soft-question, ordered-rings

A metric space is a set M together with a function $d:M \times M \rightarrow \Bbb{R} $, where $d$ satisfies:

- $d(x,y)\ge 0$
- $d(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=y$
- $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$
- $d(x,z) \le d(x,y)+ d(y,z)$

$\forall x,y,z \in M.$

Naively it seems that $\Bbb{R}$ has too much structure than what is required of it to satisfy these axioms and $d$ could map to any ordered ring.

So my question is why is $\Bbb{R}$ chosen and not a more general ring? Has there been any research on metrics that map to sets other than $\Bbb{R}$?

I have searched Google and not found anything useful. My question title seems similar to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168823/can-you-build-metric-space-theory-without-the-real-numbers) but after reading the full question text I believe they are asking different things.

Comment: Do you know that $\mathbb{R}$ is the unique Cauchy-complete totally ordered field up to isomorphism? Can you imagine why we might want these properties for what we use metrics for?

Comment: @Micheal Lee Sorry I am new to Metric Spaces. You may have to help me see why we need Cauchy-completness?

Comment: Why we might need completeness was [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1242893/415941). Metrics map to $\Bbb R$ to allow talking about this very useful property on more general sets than just $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @M. Winter Thank you for the link. So it seems like $\Bbb{R}$ is chosen because it allows for these nice properties. But still it isn't necessary to saisfy the metric axioms, so is it just a case of the general case is not interesring/useful enough to study

Comment: Also check out [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/xqx60/why_are_metric_spaces_based_on_the_reals/).

Comment: Tits buildings are thought of as "$W$-metric spaces", where the metric maps to the Coxeter group $W$. But it is only an analogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be only a single way in which generalization makes sense: by adding *infinities*, i.e. $x\in R$ with

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N:\underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_n<|x|,$$

or *infinitesimals*, i.e. $x\in R-\{0\}$ with

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N:\underbrace{|x+\cdots+x|}_n<1.$$

For ordered rings with such non-standard elements we have some interesting *non-standard metric spaces*. Let for example $R=\Bbb R^*$ a set of hyperreals. Now points in your metric space can be infinitely far apart or infinitely close together in some precise sense. Especially $\Bbb R^*$ is a non-standard metric space which [cannot be given a usual metric](https://mathoverflow.net/q/45966/108884) (except when allowing $\infty$ as distance).

- Read more here: [Which topological spaces admit a nonstandard metric?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/10870/108884)

However, when you explicitely want to avoid infinites/infinitesimals, then your generalization is merely a restriction. As it turns out, any linerly ordered ring without non-standard element is [just a subring of $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2474093/415941). So whatever you built in this way can also be considered a usual metric space with a metric $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$.

And note that the axioms of metric spaces not even use multiplication. Hence it suffices to ask for metrics $d:X\times X\to G$ for a totally ordered (abelian) *group* $G$. Still, this is only more general when we allow infinities/infinitesimals. Otherwise we are isomorphic to a subgroup of (the additive group of) $\Bbb R$ by the same argument as for rings.

Comment: Ah okay, I suspected it might be that these rings are just isomorphic to subrings of $\Bbb{R}$. Thank you for the information regarding hyperreals, would you happen to know of any good references for these non-standard metrics?

Comment: @JJGrimes No direct literatur, but this an MO post for which I added a link to my answer. Also I think "non-standard metric space" might be a good key word to start searching for.